# Highcharts small columns inside area

Tags: highcharts

I would like to add columns inside the area of chart red for negative and green for positive like attaching screenshot.

https://prnt.sc/psk7ge

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a chart with `area` and `column` series. The set the colors, use `negativeColor` and `color` options:

```
series: [{
    type: 'area',
    data: [10, 20, 10, 20, 10],
    threshold: -20
}, {
    type: 'column',
    data: [-10, 10, -15, 10, 15],
    color: 'green',
    negativeColor: 'red'
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/owh16dzL/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.negativeColor